# Understanding of Mathematica's document website

Tags: documentation

I noticed there are a lot of empty webpage in Mathematica's website. Like this one at:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjointMatrix.html

Is it only shown to paid users or it's simply empty? If it's actually empty, why put them online?

Comment: That page is not _Mathematica_ documentation. The stuff on Wolfram MathWorld is more about the mathematics. If you want the adjoint use this: `adj[m_] := 
 Map[Reverse, 
   Minors[Transpose[m], Length[m] - 1], {0, 
    1}] Table[(-1)^(i + j), {i, Length[m]}, {j, Length[m]}]` The _Mathematica_ documentation for `Minors` is here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html

Comment: Note that: 1) that's not technically a Mathematica website, but Wolfram MathWorld. 2) That page is not *completely* empty (it has links to other pages).

Comment: Also for usage in Mathematica there is `ResourceFunction["Adjugate"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mathworld.wolfram.com is not part of the official documentation and that there are placeholders at that site.

Comment: Paul, might I recommend editing your answer to assuredly declare that it is not the documentation site, and perhaps provide the location of the actual site?